# JMeter changing my namespace

Tags: soap, jmeter, xml-namespaces, xml-rpc, name-mangling

I'm trying to use JMeter to invoke a RPC/SOAP Web service and when I invoke the service my namespaces are mangled from the actual values to NS1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wpc:invoke xmlns:wpc="http://wpc.ibm.com">
    <wpc:envelope communicationVersion="5.3">
        <wpc:WPCResponseType>asynchronous</wpc:WPCResponseType>
        <wpc:wpcHeader>
            <wpc:companyName>mycompany</wpc:companyName>
            <wpc:wpsUserID>me</wpc:wpsUserID>
            <wpc:wpcUserID>wpcUsername</wpc:wpcUserID>
            <wpc:password />
            <wpc:messageIdentifier>9E2FA100-BE54-11E5-8A91-BF48E24665E0</wpc:messageIdentifier>
            <wpc:timestamp>2016-01-18</wpc:timestamp>
            <wpc:supplierId><![CDATA[0Z188]]></wpc:supplierId>
            <wpc:localeForDisplay>en_US</wpc:localeForDisplay>
            <wpc:localeRestriction>en_US</wpc:localeRestriction>
        </wpc:wpcHeader>
        <wpc:wpcBody>
            <wpc:wpcCommand mode="ASYNC" type="UPLOAD">
                <wpc:wpcCatalogName>Item Transaction Catalog</wpc:wpcCatalogName>
                <wpc:wpcFileDocStorePath>test_data/upload/0003_items.csv</wpc:wpcFileDocStorePath>
                <wpc:wpcUpdateOnly>false</wpc:wpcUpdateOnly>
            </wpc:wpcCommand>
        </wpc:wpcBody>
    </wpc:envelope>
</wpc:invoke>
```

Changes to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:invoke xmlns:ns1="http://wpc.ibm.com">
    <ns1:envelope communicationVersion="5.3">
        <ns1:WPCResponseType>asynchronous</ns1:WPCResponseType>
        <ns1:wpcHeader>
            <ns1:companyName>mycompany</ns1:companyName>
            <ns1:wpsUserID>me</ns1:wpsUserID>
            <ns1:wpcUserID>wpcUsername</ns1:wpcUserID>
            <ns1:password/>
            <ns1:messageIdentifier>9E2FA100-BE54-11E5-8A91-BF48E24665E0</ns1:messageIdentifier>
            <ns1:timestamp>2016-01-18</ns1:timestamp>
            <ns1:supplierId><![CDATA[0Z188]]></ns1:supplierId>
            <ns1:localeForDisplay>en_US</ns1:localeForDisplay>
            <ns1:localeRestriction>en_US</ns1:localeRestriction>
        </ns1:wpcHeader>
        <ns1:wpcBody>
            <ns1:wpcCommand mode="ASYNC" type="UPLOAD">
                <ns1:wpcCatalogName>Item Transaction Catalog</ns1:wpcCatalogName>
                <ns1:wpcFileDocStorePath>test_data/upload/0003_items.csv</ns1:wpcFileDocStorePath>
                <ns1:wpcUpdateOnly>false</ns1:wpcUpdateOnly>
            </ns1:wpcCommand>
        </ns1:wpcBody>
    </ns1:envelope>
</ns1:invoke>
```

There must be a setting in JMeter to keep the message from being transformed from my original meaningful namespace to this arbitrary namespace called NS1? When the message is received at the target endpoint it cannot parse the request because of this semantic error.

Any/all replies are appreciated! 
MG

Comment: How do you send your request? Which sampler is that?

Comment: Sampler is SOAP/RPC. The request above is the data in the JMeter sampler.

Comment: Then, you know what, I believe that's nothing with JMeter, it just sends the stuff raw. Check your server behavior and/or the chain in between, if any.

Comment: Ah, hold on, another thing: what are your request headers? Show your Header Manager, please.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The request / response doesn't match, as I said before the context is accessed as follows: String requestMessage = request.getSOAPEnvelope().getBody().getChildElements().next().toString();
         logger.logDebug("Invoke: request message received - " + requestMessage);

Comment: No headers are set.  Would setting the header prevent the NS from being mangled?

Comment: More specific on what, sorry? The HTTP Header Manager in your test plan?     I can't be more specific here - just show it if you have it.

Comment: There is not HTTP Header Manager.  Is that my problem? I need to set the NS in the header?

Comment: As for determining the EXACT point of failure - the only thing I can suggest for now is tracing at every link of the network chain from your JMeter to your handler in the WebSphere, where you call for requestMessage. You lack proof JMeter changes anything, right? So set the recording proxy at your JMeter machine (Fiddler, for example), set JMeter to send through it and check what you have at this point. Then apply similar method further up the chain to sniff what's going through.

Comment: Hold on, is that a SOAP request? What you shown here - is that a *whole* SOAP request you're sending towards your server? Or just the body part?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter should not change anything in the request body, maybe it is an issues with your web service? Double check the request which is being sent by JMeter using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/)

[image: JMeter namespace]

In any case try switching to [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, this is recommended way of sending web service requests (just don't forget to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send `Content-Type` and `SOAPAction` headers).

References:

- [JMeter User's Manual: Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)